# Full overlay hinge with a 1/2 inch cabinet door

Tags: hinges

I am building a frameless cabinet for an RV with 1/2 cabinet grade plywood. I was planning to use the euro style hinges for a full overlay door but the hole for the cup is deeper than my material.

What type of hinge should I use to get a 1/2 inch overlay? I would like the hinge to be concealed.

I have tried full and half overlay euro style hinges without success. I added blocking to a test door to try to make the cup fit in the door but wasn't able to get the door to fit right against the cabinet frame.

I have searched various forums for this specific question but haven't been able to find my exact question. I have looked at Rockler and other hardware sites to see if I could find a hinge that looked like it would work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. SE values Qs where it's clear what research was done, and in fact the downvote arrow specifically says "This question does not show any research effort..." So, what searches did you try and come up short?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know the construction of the cabinet.   Is it frameless, full face frame, ?

Comment: I edited my post to include more info.

Comment: Thanks for the added info. The Answer from @WalnutClose I imagine is going to do you, but FWIW I wanted to mention searching online using various search terms I found some suitable and possible hinges (one made for material 12-19mm so perfect, another fine for 1/2", but only semi-concealed). None of the sellers would have been viable for you since I'm in Europe so postage would have been ridiculous, but in case it's of future help the final search included the word "shallow" which I wouldn't have thought to search for myself but was used in one of the hinges I found along the way.

Answer (score 2):

For your application, you want a frameless, surface mount, (full) overlay hinge.   They are rather specialty items, but [here is an example](https://www.wwhardware.com/xxi-surface-mount-concealed-hinge-laxx1), or a higher end version [here](https://www.rockler.com/175-fully-concealed-hinges).   You will need short screws, and may be pushing the holding power of the screws with only 1/2" material.

An alternative to those would be semi-concealed [Youngdale hinges](https://www.wwhardware.com/shop-hardware/hinges?cat=872).   These can be found for door thicknesses as small as 1/2", although, again, you might have to source screws other than those packaged with the hinges.